# Magento 2 order confirmation email not sent

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, zend-framework

I'm working on a clients' store, and face a problem with no order confirmations being sent.

The following error is logged in system.log:

```
[2019-06-11 11:53:04] main.ERROR: Invalid address format [] []
```

Looking for that error, I see that it is generated here:

**Zend\Mail\Address.php**

```
public static function fromString($address, $comment = null)
    {
        if (! preg_match('/^((?P<name>.*)<(?P<namedEmail>[^>]+)>|(?P<email>.+))$/', $address, $matches)) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException('Invalid address format');
        }
```

Address used:
Firstname Surname
Street 1
Village, 4444GH
Nederland
T: 1234567890
info@modl-design.com

What is the exact issue? Im not the best at reading Regex so looking for the problem is hard in this case.

Comment: can you also share the dummy address and format you are using?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava post updated with the information. However, I have tried many formats and all result in the same.

Comment: may be check  ` info@modl-design.com` does have   some html code.Please check at database  at order_address tabke

Comment: @AmitBera all database records seem fine. How can I debug a Zend class? maybe logging $address somewhere will help me

Comment: update: logging the $address in Zend\Mail\Address.php gives: info@modl-design.com, now I have no idea what is going wrong. If anyone knows more an answer would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sales email copy field in Magento 2 Configuration had a wrong value:

```
info@mail.com,
```

Commas are used to separate multiple e-mailaddresses that a order confirmation copy need to be send to, but no second email was entered.

This caused Zend\Mail\Address.php to fail, trying to preg_match an empty string.

Will let Magento 2 developers know that this error reporting has to be improved.